# Variable in loop ng-click angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting

My code snippet looks like:

```
<a href="#" class="checkl" ng-selected="display_label" ng-click="check()">display_label}</a>
```

Which sits in a loop and renders everything correctly, However I'd like to simply add a value I pass to check() which should live inside, as the logic will change for different data, I can do this easily with a select drop down, however lists seem to be slightly different.

So on select I could add for example value="option" and when I call check() it would go across correctly to my function, however just need a pointer for hrefs.

Comment: What's the problem, again?

Comment: With the information you give and the code snippet, it isn't very clear what you want to achieve. If you want to pass a value to check(), can't you simply give the function a parameter?

Comment: sending a value="option" from href so the value is actually passed